# cannot display the entire contents of the csv file

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, preprocessor, enumerate

I have a problem that I can't display all the data in the csv file, the data that is output from the kede below only shows 1 line in my file, is there a solution for this

```
with open('test.csv','r') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
for f, row in enumerate(reader):
  isi = row[0].split(' ')[0]
print(isi)
```

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you might be reassigning isi in the loop, but then you seem to print the value of isi after the loop is done (if the code on my phone is being viewed right). What happens if you indent the print statement to have the same indentation as the isi variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what it looks like, you might want to try indenting the `print(isi)` statement at the end so that it lines up under the `isi = row[].split(' ')[0]` line.

Also, I adjusted the indentation in the earlier part of your example code so that it runs on my side.

Here is an example of what this could look like:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for f, row in enumerate(reader):
        isi = row[0].split(' ')[0]
        print(isi)
```

Using an example `test.csv` file like this:

```
a;b;c
d;e;f
g;h;i
```

The output should look like this:

```
a
d
g
```